# Package uses root namespace that is one of my main class names

Tags: c#, namespaces, nuget, nuget-package, name-collision

I'm using IronPython for my project. The setup is following:

```
Project.Main
  - MyProject.Python
     - IronPython package
```

Project.Main has a class called `Community` that is one of the main classes. It is used *everywhere*.

Now has IronPython a *namespace* called **Community**.CsharpSqlite with a class called Sqlite3.

- I do *not* need to reference this class within MyProject.Main
- I am not using any classes directly from the IronPython package within MyProject.Main
- I only refer to wrapper classes in MyProject.Python.

All my code doesn't compile anymore though because I'm getting:

> Error CS0118  'Community' is a namespace but is used like a type

This is a very large project and I do not want to start prefixing all my references to the Community class with a namespace prefix.

- Is there any workaround?
- Can I expose the IronPython namespaces only to MyProject.Python?
- I tried both Aliases and the PrivateAssets option but I get a warning symbol within the solution explorer and it does not seem to work (still the CS0118)
- see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files

**Example project:**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hayi3a4ctrh8rlx/NamespaceProblem.zip?dl=0

Comment: I've just tried to repro your problem but the details here are fairly sparse and I'm not seeing it. In *my* attempt I created a console application targetting .NET Core 3.1. I called it `Project.Main` (and so that's the namespace for the classes within). I added a class called `Community` and created an instance inside my `Program.Main` method. I then created a library project called `MyProject.Python`, referenced that from `Project.Main` and in `MyProject.Python` I installed the IronPython 2.7.11 Nuget package. Not seeing a problem yet. Please add details like this to the point where it fails

Comment: Hi @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I have added an example project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update:

To fix this we need to edit the *ConsoleApp1*`.csproj` file and add at the bottom:

```xml
  <Target Name="ChangeAliasesOfStrongNameAssemblies" BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)' == 'IronPython.SQLite'">
        <Aliases>IronPythonCommunity</Aliases>
      </ReferencePath>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
<!-- </Project> -->
```

Then we can load the new modified external alias in our code with the following:

```cs
extern alias IronPythonCommunity;
using Community = MyProject.Python.Community;
using System;
```

---

#### Old:

As far as I know you cannot change the Namespace of an imported DLL or NuGet. Usually you want to either use the using like

```cs
using Community = MyProj.MyProject.Python;
```

or use the fully qualified namespace like (you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for replace all occurrences of `Community` with `MyProject.Python.Community`):

```cs
static void Test(MyProject.Python.Community x)
{
}
```

Comment: Didn't had time to check, but looks like exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks!